# mysql inner join on two tables

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

Columns in table `wp_users`:

```
id
user_login
```

Columns in table `wp_usermeta`:

```
 user_id
 meta_key [if equals 'primaryblog']
 metav_value
```

The id in `wp_users` and the user-id in `wp_usermeta` are same. I am expecting the result as

```
id, user_login, meta_key, meta_value
```

I tried:

```
select a.user_id,a.meta_key,a.meta_value 
from wp_usermeta as a 
where meta_key = 'primaryblog' 
inner join b.id, b.user_login 
from wp_users as b on a.user_id=b.id
```

How to get the intended result?

Comment: `JOINS` should come before the `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JOIN comes before the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT 
  a.id, a.user_login, b.meta_key, b.meta_value
FROM wp_users a
JOIN wp_usermeta b ON a.id = b.user_id
WHERE meta_key = 'primaryblog';
```